# MS Access large matrix workaround multiselect matches

Tags: ms-access, matrix, duplicates

My issue is not knowing what words to search for to solve this issue, apologies in advance.

In order to work around the maximum number of columns on a very large matrix, individual pairs were created within a table [Table1].  This [Table1] stores values based on how related elements of the table are.

```
[OrginalMatrix]
 ,a,b,c,d,e,f,...
a,0,1,2,3,4,5,...
b,1,0,4,6,7,5,...
c,2,4,0,1,3,4,...

[Table1]
a,b,1
a,c,2
a,d,3
a,e,4
a,f,5
a,...,...
b,a,1
b,c,4
b,...,...
```

Another table [Table2] contains a key to match with those values as headers from [Table1].  Multiple unique IDs in [Table2] can contain multiple keys to values in [Table1].

```
[Table2]
1112,a,field1,field2,field3,...
1113,b,field1,field2,field3,...
1114,c,field1,field2,field3,...
1112,d,field1,field2,field3,...
```

Currently my goal is to filter by fieldX then identify duplicate IDs in [Table2] then provide a query of [Table1] with [Table2].  The query would idealy only show the unique IDs and only the values where they matched on the matrix, instead I can only produce the unique IDs with every match to the matrix right now.

```
[DesiredOut]
1112,a,d,3
1112,d,a,3

[CurrentOut]
1112,a,b,1
1112,a,c,2
1112,a,d,3
1112,a,...
```

The reason using [CurrentOut] does not make sense to me is that it cannot, that I am aware of, be filtered to contain only those values that are matches of conditions from [Table2].  Eventually this data will be used as a form that one should be able to select a row from [Table2] and only show the few, if any, matches in the matrix.

Is there a better way to make a matrix and match these values in access?  Is there a way to get the IDs from one table to return multiple value from another table into the same field?  Can this be achieved a more effiecent way(ie, use python to create a separate table)?  (mainly looking for a conceptual answer, not necessarily a coded one.)

Thank you!

Code view Edit:

```
SELECT StatusInput_OLD.* INTO StaphStatus
FROM StatusInput_OLD
WHERE (((StatusInput_OLD.organism_name)="X" Or (StatusInput_OLD.organism_name)="Y"));

SELECT StaphStatus.host_id, StaphStatus.strain_id, StaphStatus.organism_name, StaphStatus.isolate INTO DuplicatesFromStaphStatus
FROM StaphStatus
WHERE (((StaphStatus.host_id) In (SELECT [host_id] FROM [StaphStatus] As Tmp GROUP BY [host_id] HAVING Count(*)>1 )))
ORDER BY StaphStatus.host_id;

SELECT DuplicatesFromStaphStatus.host_id, DuplicatesFromStaphStatus.strain_id, CombinedStrains.strain2, CombinedStrains.distance
FROM DuplicatesFromStaphStatus INNER JOIN CombinedStrains ON DuplicatesFromStaphStatus.strain_id = CombinedStrains.strain1
ORDER BY DuplicatesFromStaphStatus.host_id, DuplicatesFromStaphStatus.strain_id, CombinedStrains.strain2;
```

Comment: can you show us the code that produces the current output?  Also, what are field1, field2, etc in table2?

Comment: I can show some of this information, like the code to get there, but this is hospital data, and cannot be released.  SELECT StatusInput_OLD.* INTO StaphStatus
FROM StatusInput_OLD
WHERE (((StatusInput_OLD.organism_name)="Staphylococcus aureus" Or (StatusInput_OLD.organism_name)="Methicillin resistant Staphylococcus aureus (MRSA)"));

Comment: I think this is still too vague for me to help.  Can you explain step by step what you'

Comment: I think this is still too vague for me to help.  I think I see the transition from Original data to Table1.  I don't understand Table2 - are field1, field2, etc the  same as the columns in the original data?  How are you using Table2 to get the desired output?  Can you provide some better examples, with some dummy data? (Sorry - timed out of the prior comment)